# Software Plotting Tropical Curves

Tags: tropical-geometry

I'm an undergrad student and currently working on my paper focusing on Tropical Math. Can anyone suggest for any software that could plot tropical curves easily? Help please!

Comment: I am not sure this helps, but here is a python script which draws some random tropical curves http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs595s14/drawtrop.py

Comment: @them ,, i still need to learn python... :(